# set the input value with the url parameter

Tags: javascript, php

the url of my application is like: `localhost:/home.php?name=xxxx#!/loadCheckout`
where xxxx is variable.
I also have an input
`<input type = "text name =" c_name "value =" ">`
I would like to assign to the value of my input only the value XXXX

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should look into URLSearchParams. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get

Answer (score 0):

this would do the trick if you want to do it from the backend(php).. `value="<?php if(isset($_GET['name'])) echo $_GET['name']?>"`

Comment: when i var_dump($_GET['name']); i have NULL

Comment: are you using POST method? if so then switch to $_POST for both instances

Comment: I'm using the GET method it works with a simple url. but with the `#!/loadCheckout` in the end of the URL it gives NULL